# Oracle BI Scheduler Config settings

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g

Following is the default configuration for purge settings of Scheduler Service in Oracle BI

```
<PurgeInstDays>7</PurgeInstDays>
<PurgeIntervalMinutes>5</PurgeIntervalMinutes>
```

What should the settings be changed to so that records are never purged and persist forever?
I tried changing it to 0 but that would immediately clean up the records.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but removing these tags might help. 
Shut down scheduler, remove these two tags and start scheduler. ( Please take backup of config file before trying out).